# Set Visible true for a component after the page loads using Java script

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf, webcenter

I have the below requirement:
I am using and ADF jsff page. On that page, i have a SelectBooleanCheckbox which gets rendered even before the entire page content load and is therefore available for the user to click which is not desirable. I want to set visibility as false for that component and then use Javascript later to make it visible only after the entire page loads.
Thoughts?

Comment: Add `display: none;` to the style attribute of the checkbox. Then remove this property when  the document ready function is fired.

Comment: Initially add visibility:hidden to the check box. change this to visibility: visible once the page is loaded. window.onload.

Comment: Use `Render` property than visible

Answer (score 0):

for example This is the HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"  style="display:none">
```

you can add this for body tag :

```
<body onload="checkbox()">
```

this is the function with JS and Jquery examples (**use only one option**):

```
function checkbox(){

 document.getElementById("checkbox").style.display=""; // option 1
 $("#checkbox").fadeIn();// option 2
 $("#checkbox").show();// option 3

 }
```

if you need to be after a while ,for example 1 second   :

```
function checkbox(){

 setTimeout(function(){   document.getElementById("checkbox").style.display="";}, 1000); // option 1
 $("#checkbox").fadeIn(1000);// option 2
 $("#checkbox").show(1000);// option 3

 }
```

Comment: I have written below code: In the jspx, i have added the method function onPageLoad(evt) {
  $("input[name*='acceptTermsConditionBox']").attr("visible", true);
 } In the jsff his component's visiblity is set to false and the clientComponent is set to true. I am trying to set it false after the page loads using this method.